# Getting the field of an object

Tags: php, laravel

I have objects like below

```
{
"user": "58a9bf92e0f78000055dd932",
"type": "template_created",
"count": 2
}
```

I need to get 'user' field, `..->type` returns "template_created" and `..->count` gives its value but `..->user` returns null. These objects come from mongodb aggregation framework by the way.

Comment: `$data = json_decode($data)` then `$data->user`

Comment: Does that value contain some sort of encription or hashing?

Comment: I think so, @urfusion it works!

Comment: @nullpointer : Cool. Glad to know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
$data = json_decode($data); //where $data contain the json
$data->user;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks, like your objects are *json-encoded*. This means, you can use the native php functions `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` to process them. In your example, you can deserialize the object by calling

```
$obj = json_decode($str);
```

with `$str` being the data you show above. Now you can access the fields of this object with standard php access methods like

```
$type = $obj->type;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to check errors after `json_decode`, like this:

```
$payload = json_decode($data);
if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Invalid JSON.');
}
// also you cah check this
if (property_exists($payload, 'user')) {
    var_export($payload->user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve with two ways :-

```
$data = '{
    "user": "58a9bf92e0f78000055dd932",
    "type": "template_created",
    "count": 2
    }';
$objectdata = json_decode($data); //stclassobject
echo $objectdata->count;
  --------OR-------
$arraydata= json_decode($data,true); //convert to array
echo $arraydata['count'];
```

Hope it hepls!